# android httpclient ssl certificate not trusted godaddy ssl

Tags: android, ssl, httpclient

I have a GoDaddy ssl certificate on my server, and when I try accessing the url with my android app it throws an exception: "Not trusted server certificate"

My code is:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
return(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified that you've installed the intermediate certificates on your server properly?

Comment: Yes, it was solved with the Godaddy support. Thanks